# Use a Max inside a Q query in Django

Tags: sql, django, filter, orm

I am using Django Q objects to automatize the construction of complex queries from a textual description.

In some of my queries, I need to combine classic Q queries, with *Max* operator as in:

```
Book.objects.filter(Q(....) & Q(...) ....).aggregate(Max('price'))
```

Is there a way to express the Max filter as a Q() filter, so that I can use a simple chain of:

```
filter(Q(...) & Q(...) & Qmax(...))
```

which would be more convenient in the frame of my query-generator algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your query like this :

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models import Q

query = Book.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
```

And use this result to further filter your queryset :

```
query_set = Book.objects.filter(Q(...) & Q(...) & Q(price= query['price__max']))
```

Comment: Thank you Prakhar! That is exactly what I was looking for!
By the way, do you know if it is compatible with a search upon key-value of a Postgres JSONField?

Comment: @matt Glad my answer helped you. I am no expert in Postgres,but I think it will be compatible for JSONField.I am not so sure.